# How does one tackle over-fitting in NLP based CNN models for multiclass text classification with word embeddings?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, stanford-nlp, overfitting-underfitting

(Problem: Overfitting issues in a multiclass text classification problem)
In my personal project, the objective is to classify the industry tags of a company based on the company description. The steps I've taken are:

1. Removing stopwords, punctuations, spaces, etc, and splitting the description into tokens.
2. Converted the labels and tokens into word vectors.
3. Convert the tokens into a word embedding model.
4. Set up the CNN with 62 output nodes. (62 distinct industry tags to classify)

---

Image/Dataset Link for reference: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yLW2YepoHvSp_koHDDzcAAJBIaYQIen0?usp=sharing

---

The issue I face is that the model overfits regardless of the alterations I make. (Ends early due to callback I set up for loss)
[CNN accuracy][7]

```
max_features = 700
maxlen = 200
embedding_dims = 50
filters = 200
kernel_size = 3
hidden_dims = 160
es_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

model.add(Conv1D(filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(62))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X_train, y_label_train,
              batch_size=64,
              epochs=50,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_label_test),
              callbacks=[es_callback])
```

Code Link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1YqbhPX6e4bJ5FnbfHj7fTQH4tUe6diva?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I find the question quite general, although it is a useful one not only for NLP. Therefore, I think there are a lot of topics to cover in order to tackle this issue properly. I am advising you to firstly focus on the data pre-processing steps, hence the code snippet here describing the neural network architecture (in my opinion) might be the last step. Based on a first look at your code at colab I would advise:

- Better data pre-processing

  - ***More correct data preprocessing***:

    - For example, I think you applied the following only on the train data  `X['Text_Clean'] = X['Business Description'].apply(lambda x: remove_punct(x))`, and I didn't see a pipeline for similar transformations on the test set, nor a direct transformation.

    - You applied word embeddings on the **tokens**. I believe they would give greater value to your ***text*** "text_final" feature so that you could gain value from the ***semantic representations*** of the text narrative.
  - In [general](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-text-preprocessing-a-practical-guide-and-template-d80874676e79) I would say: convert to lower-case, removal of HTML tags, punctuation, non-alphabetic characters, removal of stopwords/adding some other words in the stopwords list based on your specific text, fixing some informal text in the vocabulary, e.g. "what's" -> "what is", and stemming to convert words with roughly the same semantics to one standard form.
  - [Imbalanced Classification Problems](https://machinelearningmastery.com/what-is-imbalanced-classification/): It occurs

> when the number of examples in the training dataset for each class
> label is not balanced.

Put it simply, when a small number of your tags occupy a large number of your labels associated with your text, then not much training happens on the rest of the "minority" tags to be learned.

- [Feature Engineering](https://towardsdatascience.com/text-analysis-feature-engineering-with-nlp-502d6ea9225d): You can create extra features and metadata to enhance training and learning. For example, you can add a column providing the sentiment of every instance, and/or you can apply topic modeling as an extra attribute (they would be similar to the "tokens" you have put on the dataframe, supporting -and not replacing- the main text attribute).

Lastly, I would not consider it a bad idea to firstly begin with [TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) and observe the accuracy there before proceeding to neural networks. If the above is not enough, you can also explore more robust transfer learning and [pre-trained models](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-pre-trained-model-series-to-use-for-nlp-with-transfer-learning-b2e45c1c275b) while using deep neural networks.